# How to make the note of ComBoBox in Delphi

Tags: delphi

in my project I want to make some note when user move mouse over the ComboBox Item, 
Ex : I have a ComboBox and the Items are : Bob's phone,Robert's phone,... 
When user move mouse over Bob's phone then the label will appear at the Position of Mouse in ComboBox and Label's content is : 05498762,.

Please help me and thanks much!!!

Comment: A combobox only shows one item unless it's dropped down. While it's dropped down, you can't get information on which item is under the mouse. If you need that sort of behavior, use a listbox or listview instead, which shows multiple items.

Comment: Mybe `Hint` property can do the job with the `ItemIndex` of the combobox

Comment: @Sami hovering over the iyems of the dropped down list does not change the ItemIndex.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I say after selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work on mouse move after selection after you set `ShowHint` to true:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Select(Sender: TObject);
begin
case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of
  0: ComboBox1.Hint := '05498762';
  1: ComboBox1.Hint := '';
  .
  .
  .
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display a hint while the user is actively moving the mouse over the `TComboBox` items, you can do the following:

---

If the `TComboBox.Style` property is set to `csSimple`, the ComboBox's ListBox is always visible.  However, the `OnMouseMove` event is not exposed, and even if you assign it manually, it is not triggered when moving the mouse over the ComboBox's ListBox, only its Edit field.  However, you can use the `TApplication.OnShowHint` event instead, or subclass the `TComboBox` itself to intercept the `CM_HINTSHOW` message directly.  Either way will provide you with a reference/pointer to a `THintInfo` record.  You can use the `THintInfo.CursorPos` field to determine the ListBox item that is currently under the mouse:

- call `GetComboBoxInfo()` to get the ComboBox's ListBox `HWND`.
- then call `MapWindowPoints()` to translate the `CursorPos` coordinates from ComboBox client coordinates to ListBox client coordinates.
- then send a `LB_ITEMFROMPOINT` message to the ListBox with the translated coordinates.

That will give you the index of the item that is closest to the coordinates.  You can then set the `THintInfo.HintStr` field with the desired text.  You should also set the `THintInfo.CursorRect` field with the rectangle returned by sending a  `LB_GETITEMRECT` message to the ListBox (use `MapWindowPoints()` to convert the rectangle from ListBox client coordinates to ComboBox client coordinates).  When the mouse moves outside of the rectangle, a new `OnShowHint`/`CM_HINTSHOW` will be issued, and you can then update the `THintInfo` with details from the ListBox item that is now under the mouse.

---

If the `TComboBox.Style` property is not set to `csSimple`, the ListBox is only visible when it is dropped down.  The `OnShowHint`/`CM_HINTSHOW` trick will not work in this situation.  However, you can use the `TComboBox.OnDropDown` event to manually subclass the ListBox directly (and the `OnCloseUp` event to remove the subclass), using `SetWindowLongPtr()` or `SetWindowSubclass()`.  That will allow you to intercept `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages that are sent directly to the ListBox, and then you can send `LB_ITEMFROMPOINT` to the ListBox with the provided mouse coordinates.

However, to actually display a hint, it is not enough to just set the `TComboBox.Hint` property in this situation (it won't be displayed, as the dropped-down list is basically acting as a modal window and is blocking the normal hint mechanism). You will have to display your own hint window manually, such as by using the `THintWindow` class directly.